# Avoid sending completed order status email notification for a specific user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have a user role for wholesale customers (wholesale_customer). When I mark an order as completed a notification is send to customers. This is ok for my regular customers but I would like to disable/remove the notification for wholesale customers.

What I've got so far:

```
function do_not_send_some_email_notifications(WC_Emails $wc_emails) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    if ( $order->user_id > 0 ) {
    $user_id = $order->user_id;
    $get_user_data = get_userdata($user_id); 

    $user_roles = $get_user_data->roles;
        if (in_array('wholesale_customer', $user_roles)) {
            remove_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array($wc_emails->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger'));

        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_email', 'do_not_send_some_email_notifications');
```

I have tested this but it's not working.

It would be very nice if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated 2:** I finally find the right hook to make it work. I have revisited your code a little bit using a very similar custom function hooked in the **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`** action hook.

Here is the code:

```
function custom_conditional_email_notifications( $order_id ) {
    // Set HERE the targetted user role
    $targeted_user_role = 'wholesale_customer';

    // Get the order object, the user ID, and the user role.
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $user_id =  $order->get_user_id();
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

    if ( in_array( $targeted_user_role, $user_info->roles ) && $user_id > 0 )
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array(
            $wc_emails->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'],
            'trigger'
        ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_conditional_email_notifications' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Only the first bit with Targeted_user_role is giving an error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='). Is there a small error in the code maybe?

Comment: Thanks again. When I test this code a user with user role 'wholesale_customer' is still receiving the notification when the order is marked completed. Should I change 'administrator' to 'wholesale_customer' as well?

Comment: I have tried the new code but it is still not working. I have tried it with two accounts (administrator and wholesale customer). In both cases I received the notification after marking the order as completed. Possibly a conflict with another plugin / piece of code?